# Как в php раскодировать строку, закодированную в js с помощью escape()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте.
Так как я отправляю форму аяксом, мне приходится данные из textarea пропускать через escape(). Вопрос в том, можно ли как то на php декодировать в нормальные символы? Вот функция отправки.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#form');
        var formData = form.serialize();
        var body = tinymce.editors['body'].getContent();
        $.ajax({
            url     : form.attr("action"),
            type    : form.attr("method"),
            data    :  formData + '&body=' + escape(body),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },
            error :function( errors ) {
                output = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Возникла ошибка</h4><ul>";
                $.each(errors.responseJSON, function(index, error){
                    output += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
                });
                output += "</ul></div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
            },
            success: function(data){
                output = "<div class='alert alert-success'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Готово</h4>";
                output +=  data.success;
                output += "</div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace('{{ url('panel/article') }}')}, 3500
                );
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря, `escape` слышу первый раз. Обычно использую аналогичную (по всей видимости) `encodeURIComponent`. Думаю, разница невелика. Обратный процесс на сервере - `urldecode`:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php

P.S.

Загуглил `escape` и ознакомился с описанием. Вам тоже рекомендую: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Переходите, все же, на `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Я пробовал urlencode перед занесением в бд, ничего не изменилось. Сейчас попробую с вашей функцией

Comment: @Alex_01 `urlencode` - кодирует строку. `urldecode` - раскодирует. С `urlencode` вы, зачем-то, кодировали уже закодированное. Получалось, думаю, еще хуже )

Comment: Спасибо большое вам за помощ)действительно,я все перепутал) сейчас исправил) еще раз спасибо)